# by November 1918 he had moved to Munich

Tags: present-perfect

*He [Alfred Rosenberg] was a witness to the October Revolution which brought the Bolsheviki to power in Russia. He returned to Reval and **by November 1918 he had moved to Munich**.*

Can you explain to me the usage of the Past Perfect in my excerpt. Rosenberg firstly returned to Reval and then he moved to Munich. I really do not understand the used tense.

Comment: As of November 1918 his move to Munich was complete.  The prepositional phrase headed by **by** licenses the past perfect; it sets a reference time in the past, a *terminus ad quem* as of which the relocation was completed.

Comment: Compare: *At 5AM today I made myself a cup of coffee. By 5:05AM today I had drunk a cup of coffee.*

Comment: And this is precisely what I am not able to understand. The past perfect is used for the situation that occured after the other situation.

Comment: In this case, the earlier action is the relocation to Munich, and the (later) reference time/terminus is "by November 1918". The return to Reval is irrelevant here.  In my example with the coffee, the making of the coffee at 5AM is irrelevant to the choice of past perfect with **by 5:05 AM**.  The reference time is 5:05AM, not 5AM.  As I write in my first comment above, **by** + time-phrase establishes a *terminus ad quem*, which is the reference time for the earlier action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction "by [date/time] had done X" indicates that X was completed by the indicated date or time. It does not say just when it was done, just that it was some time before that date.

In this case, the writer probably doesn't know the exact date that Rosenberg moved to Munich. If he knew that it was on October 17, he probably would have written, "... and on October 17 he moved to Munich." But he has reason to believe that Rosenberg was in Munich in November -- probably some documentation of the man living there or doing something there in November -- so he can say that, by that date, he had moved.

You might also use this construction when the date is an important deadline or otherwise significant. "By quitting time Bob had the report finished." "By the day he got married he had resolved to be faithful." Etc.